# Google Firebase Messaging API facing CORS error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, capacitor

Hi there Guys i'm tryng to subscribe Firebase Cloud Messaging channels with provided token via capacitor/ioni app using PWA. But i got a CORS issue when i publish the www folder, instead on localhost it is working
This is the code im using in .ts file

```
this.devices = response;
        FirebaseMessaging.requestPermissions().then(result => {
          if(result.receive === 'granted')
          {
            FirebaseMessaging.getToken(
              {
                vapidKey: 'my-vapid-key',
              }
            ).then( result => {
              const token = result.token;
              this.devices.forEach(i => {
                let topic = i.serial
                fetch('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/'+ token +'/rel/topics/'+ topic, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: new Headers({
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With",  
                    'Authorization': 'key=my-key'
                  })
                }).then(response => {
                  alert('Fatto')
                  if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 400) {
                    throw 'Error subscribing to topic: '+response.status + ' - ' + response.text();
                  }
                  console.log('Subscribed to "'+topic+'"');
                }).catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
                })
                
              })
               
              this.addReceivedListener();
```

the error i faced is: "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/xxxxxxxxtokeeeen/rel/topics/mytopic' from origin 'https://mysite.site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Answer (score 1):

there is no CORS on the other side, so we need to disable it and its working

Comment: what other side?